# How can I be sure my application is published on the Android Market?

Tags: google-play, publishing

I published my first application on android market. In developer console, i see my app. and green check icon which means that successfully published. However, when i searched my app. in market, there is no application appears. Therefore, i asked myself some questions for feeling worried:

1. Is my app. clearly published but need some time for appearing?
2. Does it has some publishing errors in my manifest file(e.g. lack of permissions) or settings in developer console?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All applications in the Android market are tested to see they are not malicious or harmful. That's why it takes some time for your application to appear. Read google's publishing terms to see how long it should take for an application to be published.